# Getting Data from bootstrap accordion menu in view.py dynamically in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have an Accordion menu in my site which it has category, subcategory and the article, I want to be able to see which category, subcategory and article the user has clicked and filter my model based on those conditions, being article in subcategory in category.

I first tried to put the links of accordion inside a form and named each link, but that just messed up how it showed on screen.

frontend accordion:

```html
<!-- COllapsible sidebar -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">


        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-1 " id="sidebar">
            <div class="list-group panel">
                
                <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Item 1</span> </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu1">
                    
                    <a href="#menu1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 1 </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 1 a</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 2 b</a>
                        
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                            
                            <a href="#menu1sub1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c.3 </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1sub1">
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 4 d</a>
                        <a href="#menu1sub1sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false">Subitem 5 e </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub2">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.1</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any suggestion or alternative route to get what I want is also appreciated, all I want is to be able to filter my database from views.py, based on 3 conditions, conditions being the category, subcategory and the article which are the hierarchical steps in the accordion menu.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show some code to clarify what specifically you're looking to fix?

Comment: Please include your code if you want help. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're going back to the view when a subitem is clicked, eg `<a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>`  If you change this to `<a href="{% url 'show-item' item.id %}" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>` (assuming you have a suitable URL), that will show it.

If you specifically need the Item 1, Subitem 1 etc above, you can do

`<a href="{% url 'view-name' item1 subitem1 item.id %}" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>`

You would need a url something like:`path('myview/<str:item>/<str:subitem>/<int:item_id>/', views.MyView.as_view(), name="view-name")`